# GroupBox header text is cut off

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a `GroupBox` in XAML that houses three `RadioButton`s. Everything looks fine except that the `'g'` in my `GroupBox` header is cut off at the bottom, like this:

[image: Screenshot one]

I've read other posts with formatting issues, and have steered clear of positioning my different elements using margins. However, this doesn't seem to be my problem. I have built everything using grids (even inside my `GroupBox`), but something is still cutting my header off. Any input would be appreciated!

This is what the GroupBox looks like when the font is normal and not bold:

[image: Screenshot two]

Here is the part of my code with the `GroupBox`:

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <GroupBox Header="Current Units (English)" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="currentUnitsGroupBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="4" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".22*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".22*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".22*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=".36*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <RadioButton 
                                Content="System" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Name="systemRadio" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                FontSize="12" 
                                FontWeight="Bold" 
                                IsChecked="True" 
                                Grid.Column ="0" 

                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CurrentUnitsSystem"/>
                            <RadioButton 
                                Content="English" 
                                FontSize="12" 
                                FontWeight="Bold" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Name="englishRadio" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Grid.Column="1" 

                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CurrentUnitsEnglish"/>
                            <RadioButton 
                                Content="Metric" 
                                FontSize="12" 
                                FontWeight="Bold" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                Name="metricRadio" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                Grid.Column="2" 

                                AutomationProperties.AutomationId="CurrentUnitsMetric"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: no problem, hmm, it looks fine on my system. Get rid of the FontWeight bold on your group box, and see then. Could you attach an image after the change

Comment: Can please share the relevant part? I mean the part you are using the given text `FallEdge`

Comment: And hmm @lucas, I wonder why it looks different on my computer

Comment: I've tested it with everything that came to my mind and im not able to reproduce it. Please try the following:  `<GroupBox  FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">
                <GroupBox.Header>
                    <TextBlock Height="22" Text="Current Units (English)"></TextBlock>
                </GroupBox.Header>`

Comment: @Pine I'd play with the padding of the group box or the margins of the grid  to see if that affected what you see. Explicitly setting the background of the grid to transparent might be worth a try too.

Comment: Oh wow, that fixed it! Thank you so much @lokusking!!! Is that often a fix for text formatting? To use TextBlock?

Comment: Not really. Tbh, i have no clue, what is different in your system. It might be the Parent-Grid (you didnt show) or the the Scalingmode or the Weather in Tibet ;)

Comment: This only happens to me in design mode.  When I ran the code, the text was no longer cut.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've tested it with everything that came to my mind and im not able to reproduce it. Please try the following:

```
<GroupBox FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold"> 
    <GroupBox.Header> 
           <TextBlock Height="22" Text="Current Units (English)"/>     </GroupBox.Header>
```

Since the Header in the `GroupBox` is a `TextBlock` anyway, we do the stuff now by ourself and adjust the height a little bit

Comment: This conflicts with the styling in the rest of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<GroupBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="currentUnitsGroupBox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold">

        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock Text="Current Units (English)" Padding="5"  />
        </GroupBox.Header>

    </GroupBox>
```